# Chef: Setup concurrency with poise application python recipe

Tags: chef-infra, celery, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef with poise/application_python recipe to start Celery workers. But I didn't find how to setup concurrency of these workers.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

My recipe:

```
node['python-app'].each do |app|
  application '/srv/' + app['name'] do
    git do
      repository app['repo']
      revision app['branch'] if app['branch']
      deploy_key data_bag_item('ssh_keys', app['deploy_key'])['key'] if app['deploy_key']
    end
    virtualenv
    pip_requirements

    celery_worker do
      app_module 'tasks'
      user 'celery'
      service_name "scrawler"
    end

    celery_config do
      options do
        worker_concurrency 5  # nothing...
        concurrency 4  # nothing...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using this recipe: https://github.com/poise/application_python

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned over on the GitHub issue, you need to use the old name for the config option: `celeryd_concurrency`.